# how can I count number of digits with leading zeros in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a form where a user enters a number, say an employee ID number or something like that. The field is set to reject anything that's not a number, so they can't just put in "bob" or faceroll the keyboard or whatever. Otherwise I'd convert this to a string.

I need to further validate and make this form reject anything that doesn't match the correct number of digits, lets say 5. It also needs to count leading zeros. For example - let's assume an Employee ID of 01234, which should match 5 digits. Currently, I'm losing that leading zero and it's rejecting values like the example above.

So, how can I:

- count the number of digits in this number,
- preserve leading zeros,
- make sure they user is obligated to enter a number, with a JavaScript formula?

Comment: We need to see your code and what you've tried

Comment: store the  "number" as a string, then just use .lenght

Answer (score 2):

You should go with your original idea and use a string for such a field.
You can check whether the string is a number with a simple regex such as

```
let regex = /^[0-9]*$/;
regex.test(string);
```

It should return true if the string contains only digits.

Comment: Nice Answer, you should update the answer though to complete it. I.e, if it is true, then calculate the length of the string with regex = regex.split(""), let length = regex.length for example :)

Answer (score 1):

If you get the input element's value with `element.value` it will return a string that preserves leading zeroes.

Limiting the input field's characters is covered in [HTML text input allow only numeric input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input)

I've copied and modified the example below to show an input field that only accepts up to 8 numbers and will log the ID on submit.

```js
// Restricts input for the given textbox to the given inputFilter.
// Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/469362
function setInputFilter(textbox, inputFilter) {
  ["input", "keydown", "keyup", "mousedown", "mouseup", "select", "contextmenu", "drop"].forEach(function(event) {
    textbox.addEventListener(event, function() {
      if (inputFilter(this.value)) {
        this.oldValue = this.value;
        this.oldSelectionStart = this.selectionStart;
        this.oldSelectionEnd = this.selectionEnd;
      } else if (this.hasOwnProperty("oldValue")) {
        this.value = this.oldValue;
        this.setSelectionRange(this.oldSelectionStart, this.oldSelectionEnd);
      }
    });
  });
}

const inputField = document.getElementById("employee-id");
const submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");

setInputFilter(inputField, function(value) {
  return /^\d*$/.test(value) && (value.length <= 8);;
});
submitButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
  console.log(inputField.value)
})
```

```html
User ID: <input id="employee-id">
<button id="submit">submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<input id="number" type="text" minlength="5" maxlength="5" value="42" pattern="\d{5}">
```

Check validity via JS

```
document.querySelector('#number').checkValidity()
```

check validity via CSS

```
input {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
input:invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

if you need further validation just use javascript to validate it.